# VBA Excel/ search & replace value in next column double variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have the feeling I am close, yet I feel really far.

I have one sheet called `temp`.
In M2 there's a unique identifier so I know which row I need to find in my other sheet which is called `specs`.
The value of G2 of the sheet `temp` needs to be pasted 3 columns to the right on the searched value (in the sheet `specs`).

I came this far but now I am stuck :/

```vb
Sub search()
  Dim indexnr As String
  Dim rngFind As Range, rngLookUp As Range
  
  indexnr = Sheets("temp").Range("m2")
  Data = Sheets("temp").Range("g2")
 
  Set rngLookUp = Range("D1:D1000")
  
  Set rngFind = rngLookUp.Find(indexnr, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: `now I am stuck` - why? What doesn't work?

Comment: i am stuck cause i don't know how to replace the value .... when i execute the macro it doesn't do a thing... and i have no idea what i am doing wrong...

Comment: `rngFind = Data`?

Comment: nono i think you misunderstand me. the data variabele needs to be pasted in the the row 3 to the right of where m2 is found. so if m2 is found on D15 than i need the "data" from g2 copied to G15

Comment: Change your `.Offset(0, 1)` to `.Offset(0, 3)` and then `rngFind = Data`?

Comment: jees, i was so close thanks a lot man.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the range.find method, a For Each Next Statement should do what you need.

The range.find method returns another range object which would not paste the values inside the cell.

Try something like this:

```
For Each i in [D1:D1000] 
    tempString = i.value2

    if Instr(1,tempString,indexr,0) <> 0 then
         i.offset(0,3).value2 = tempString
    end if

next i
```